# VSCode Jupyter error when attempting to connect to remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use VSCode Remote for development on an academic cluster and I am a frequent user of the Jupyter extension. On my cluster, I launch a Jupyter instance using Slurm and then use the "Connect to a Jupyter Server" option to connect to the instance. This was working well until today, when entering the URL for the Jupyter server caused the server selection interface to disappear with no error in the gui. In the Jupyter output, the following error is displayed:

```
info 15:49:09.478: Creating server with url : <URL>
info 15:49:09.549: Creating server with url : <URL>
error 15:49:10.417: Failed to enter Jupyter Uri, Class name = k, completed in 868ms, 
                    has a falsy return value, Arg 1: "<URL>/?token=<TOKEN>", 
                    Return Value: undefined [Error: UNIX[No such file or directory]]
```

What I have tried to debug:

- Restart VSCode locally (nothing changes)
- Restart the remote server (nothing changes)
- Manually port forward and view the Jupyter notebook in Google Chrome (works)
- Check for updates (no updates available, but this behavior might have been caused by an update)

Does anyone have any advice for how to debug the Jupyter extension to figure out what is going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: did you try with accessing the port on web browser?

Comment: yes, it works when I forward the port to my local browser, but within VSCode running on the remote server it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: strange. I use VS code 1.71.2. It is working fine. May be you want to reinstall the remote SSH extension? Also, delete `.vscode-server` directory from the remote server/cluster.